# Java sound: which is more efficient - WAV or MIDI

Tags: java, audio, midi

I have a Java application that needs to play a few distinct 'sounds/riffs' to indicate status.  I would like to know whether it is better to record these as audio files (wav or whatever format) and play them back using the Java audio classes, or whether it would be better to store MIDI data and play them using the Java MIDI classes.

In my case, storage space is not a problem (within reason).  I have about 5-8 status that I would like to play different melodies for.  Each melody would be 1-3 seconds, consisting of 2-8 notes.

Comment: If you ever want to make it configurable: most user's won't know about MIDI.

Comment: If storage space is not a problem, how do you measure efficiency?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PCM (found within your WAV file) and MIDI are tools for entirely different jobs.

PCM is a way to encode audio, the sound itself.  MIDI is a way to encode messages for controlling synthesizes... note on, note off, etc.

If you're playing back music and you don't particularly need high control over what it sounds like (as each system's MIDI synth can sound different), MIDI is an efficient way to encode it.  If you need good quality instruments, vocals, etc., you need an actual sound format like PCM in WAV, MP3, AAC, etc.

Comment: Thanks.  Yes, I'm aware of the difference.  Given your comment about differences in MIDI synth, and that I don't have a storage constraint (within reason), I'll probably take the sound file approach.  It seems like it might be more reliable.